# MSQL parse dates as 21-JUN-14

Tags: mysql

I have some dates exported as varchars from an Oracle database, and the dates are in this format;

20-JAN-13

14-OCT-14 etc etc

How can I parse them? I've been trying things such as `STR_TO_DATE(next_event_date, '%d-%mmm-%YY')` but no luck, any ideas?

Kind Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 2):

Right from the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
STR_TO_DATE(next_event_date, '%d-%b-%y')
```

You should also look for the format modifiers here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the help, I only looked at the tags that begin with 'm' so that's why I missed it. Will mark as correct answer when available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(next_event_date,'%d-%M-%y');
```

Using your example.

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('14-OCT-14','%d-%M-%y');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('14-OCT-14','%d-%M-%y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2014-10-14                          | 
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20-JAN-13','%d-%M-%y');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('20-JAN-13','%d-%M-%y') |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2013-01-20                          | 
+-------------------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>